# Maven is unable to access interface.class inside dependency jar

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, fatjar

My Maven project has a custom dependency JAR which has a class file that I use in my application. This custom dependency JAR is actually a fat JAR meaning its dependency JARs are placed in a lib folder in its project structure instead of fetching them from a POM file.

`MyApplication` uses class from `customjar.package.class`:

```
    //Some code above and below
    Line 109`  CustomJar responeObject = new CustomJar();
```

`CustomJar` internally uses `libFolder.jar.interface`:

```
public class CustomJar implements LibFolderJarInterface
```

Now when I am trying to do a clean build in my application using `mvn clean install`, I get an error stating that:

> failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ABC: compilation failure <insert full project path (including relative path) here>\SomeClass.java:[109:44] error: cannot access LibFolderJarInterface.class

This dependency class is present in the dependency JAR in a lib folder within an another dependency JAR. Have anyone encountered this before? Any suggestions? Eclipse is able to access it but Maven is unable to. Should I request the team that made this customJar to refactor their project structure to use the components in such a way that Maven can access it or should I add any changes to my POM. Please advice.

Comment: Is that class defined public accessible? Sounds it is not ....

Comment: Yes its a public interface.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what this means: `..This custom dependency Jar is actually a fat jar meaning its dependency jars are placed in a lib`?

Comment: Maven usually downloads the dependencies from a pom file. But the developers who developed this fat jar put the dependencies into a lib folder within the project structure making the jar heavy hence the name fat jar.

Comment: I understand what a fat jar is and also using a lib directory and understand Maven very well and how it works, but it is bad idea using fat-jar's in general instead of real dependencies etc. and a fat-jar usually produces other problems. Furthermore without the full code project or at least an example project it's hard to say what the problem is. The full poms would also be helpful....